# Download SSRS report to a custom shared path

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2019

Is possible to open a report and save it to a custom shared path without using the default save as button?

Like basically create a text box or similar and use it to define the shared path and when clicked it downloads the report to that path.

I could not find any relevant answers browsing the internet.

Thanks in advance.